# how to run jenkins job from slack channel

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I just wanted to know if there is any way to integrate Jenkins with slack, to run a job from slack channel or something.

For eg. we will type any command from slack channel and then the particular Jenkins job will run.
Can we do that?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a Webhook or a Remote trigger on Jenkins's side and trigger it using Slack events. Rather than pulling from Jenkins, you can push the trigger from Slack. [This](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api) is the documentation for Event API.